# Current transformer damage

Tags: current, transformer, coil, damage

Can a current transformer be damaged with an open secondary coil even if it is powered with an extremely low current?

e.g a small spark gap is made, though no plasma stream is created due to the small current the coil is fed.  This results in an open secondary, but will it damage the coil?

Comment: `This results in an open secondary` ... it is unclear if you mean that the resistance of the secondary winding measures infinity

Comment: Are you asking because you want to use a CT to produce a continuous arc?

Comment: Yeah, resistance close to infinity...

Comment: I made one, and it didn’t arc.  I’m assuming that meant it had an infinite resistance in the secondary, resulting in damage but I’m not sure.

Comment: Not a conventional way of doing things.  If you ensure your spark gap is small enough that the CT is never exposed to insulation damaging voltage or burnout causing current, you could probably make it work, but if your output circuit opened, the coil might go into higher voltage ranges and damage itself.  Within the capabilities of it's source and input, it will produce whatever voltage is necessary on the output to maintain the ratio between the current it monitors and the output current.

Comment: Did you give it an AC current to monitor?  Bear in mind it transforms current, so you have to run a current through it's primary, not simply apply a voltage.

Comment: If you're testing one for the first time, make sure you can replicate the build, start with a tiny tiny air gap and test wider and wider.

Comment: I had an ignition coil from a car.  I built a circuit which included a very low value capacitor in series with the ic.  The capacitor lowered the current too much, and no plasma stream was produced as a result (I think).  This resulted in an open secondary.  With a very low current, could the coil be damaged?  Will The primary be too high of a resistance for the current to even make it through?

Comment: Where is CT datasheet and what arc current did you estimate?  (V/ESR=I)

Comment: Im not sure.  The capacitor value was around 5nf, and was fed 240v at 50hz.  The recommended minimum for the circuit was 0.1 micro farad, so I’m assuming I way underpowered it, hence why I’m not sure if it would be damaged or not.  I could find a ds, but here is the coil I used https://www.gssautoparts.com.au/delphi-ignition-coil-set-of-6-fits-ford-falcon-ba

Comment: This is AFAICS the 4th time you've asked this same question. You're unlikely to get a different answer asking the same question. Now, if you ask a different question, like 'I've tested this ignition coil as it's intended to be used, with a 12v battery and a secondary spark gap ...' then you might get some meaningfully different responses, and might learn something about your coil.

Comment: Sorry, i'm just paranoid.  I don't have the coil anymore, and i'm being irrational because of it...